# WordPress execute specific cronjob on specific Page

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am having a small tour page that uses built-in cron jobs (wp-cron) to sync tours and sessions via an API every 4 hours and until here everything is perfect.

[image]

Now, what I am trying to achieve now is to also and "forcefully" execute this specific cronjob (regardless of it's schedule) when being on a specific page, e.g. Thank you page (not Woocommerce).

What's the best way to have this achieved? Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try by using admin_init hooks and check the page id or url then run the execute function.

```
add_action( 'travel_booking_do_tour_search_action', 'my_custom_cron_function');

function my_custom_cron_function(){
    // your execute action
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'execute_cron_on_specific_page' );

function execute_cron_on_specific_page{
    if( is_page( 2094 ) ) // page_id = 2094 (eg:thank you page)
    {
        my_custom_cron_function();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you very much. How about if I would like to "hardcode" this into that page. E.g. the thank you page is using a unique template (pageThankyou.php) so I have access to the php file.

Comment: you can replace "is_page( 2094 )" with "is_page_template( 'thank-you.php' )" or "is_page_template( 'templates/thank-you.php' )" depending on where your file exist.

You can also check on wordpress codex - 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/

Answer (score 0):

I have been left with the doubt, are you using the native Cron job of your server or the wp-cron of WordPress?

Comment: My apologies, I am using wp-cron

Comment: with that clear, the best thing to do is to disable the WordPress wp-cron and let the server cron do the job.
the reason for this is that the WordPress wp-cron is only executed when there is a user visiting the page, In addition, this consumes your site's resources, affecting its performance.
On the other hand, the server cron always runs at the defined time interval, no matter if there are visitors or not on your page.

Comment: I leave you a link with the steps:
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9948/2187/what-is-wordpress-cron-and-how-to-work-with-it/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwwJuVBhCAARIsAOPwGAQw5JkdvrE60eScMDCqPBLjlj_um-eUuVgVqen6rQ9e2PxN4AxYU-0aAjjVEALw_wcB